# Testcafe caught in page reload loop

Tags: testing, browser, automated-tests, content-security-policy, testcafe

I have a set of Testcafe tests for our application, which since recently fails to run in some of our environments. The test only opens the browser, loads the start page specified in the fixture (or navigated to in within the test) and then only appears to continuously reload the page without proceeding with the test. This happening across all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and different versions of NodeJs and Testcafe on Windows 10.
After enabling debug logging I found this message repeatedly in the log:

```
{
    cmd: 'wait-for-file-download',
    sessionId: '0X_DqYtz0'
}
```

The browser console also showed two page resources/scripts that failed to load with net::ERR_FAILED errors due to violating the Content Security Policy, so I assume that these might cause the problems. However it does not seem to have any impact on manual page interaction or automated test using other frameworks like PyTest.
While we are investigating on the conflicting resources, is there anything I can do in Testcafe to bypass the issue and allow the tests to run? Or alternatively is there a way to fail a Testcafe test when encountering this issue instead of reloading and possibly eventually timing out?

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for your question. Please share your page URL or a simple example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: I cannot provide a url, as we only observed it in our internal environment that are not publicly accessible. Meanwhile, we have also removed the root cause for the issue in the application, which is a script blocked by the CSP. However I am still concerned about how Testcafe handles this issue. Is there a way make Testcafe either ignore it or fail the test, instead of just keep polling?
This example would fail to execute while loading the page:
`fixture('Loginpage')
  .page('https://login.mypage.com')

test('valid request', async (browser) => {
    console.log('Hello world')
  });
})`

Comment: Let's continue discussing this question in the context of your [Github thread](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5309).